# Install ant1.8 or higher to Scientific Linux 6

Tags: linux, ant, yum

I am trying all day long to find how to install ant 1.8 or higher version to Scientific Linux 6 64 bit machine. I am using yum install ant but the most recent version is 1.7.

Can you help me giving some advice where to look and how to do it?
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will help you: http://wiki.cecalc.ula.ve/index.php/Installing_ant_on_Scientific_Linux